# Docker not saving file on KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, docker

I'm storing tweets into a CSV, when I run the following code in Jupyter Notebook it'll save to tweets.csv successfully.

```
with open(fName, 'a') as f:
while True:
    try:
        if (max_id <= 0):
            # to the beginning of twitter time
            if (not sinceId):
                results = api.search(q=query, count=tweetCount)
            # go to last tweet we downloaded
            else:
                results = api.search(q=query, since_id=sinceId, count=tweetCount)
        # if max_id > 0 
        else:
            # results from beginning of twitter time to max_id
            if (not sinceId):
                results = api.search(q=query, max_id=str(max_id - 1), count=tweetCount)
            # results from since_id to max_id
            else:
                results = api.search(q=searchQuery, count=tweetCount,
                                     max_id=str(max_id - 1),
                                     since_id=sinceId)
        if not results:
            print("No more tweets found")
            break
        for result in results:
            tweets_DF = pd.DataFrame({"text": [x.text for x in results]}, 
               index =[x.id for x in results])
            tweets_DF.name = 'Tweets'
            tweets_DF.index.name = "ID"
            tweets_DF.to_csv(f, header=False)
        tweetCount += len(results)
        print("Downloaded {0} tweets".format(tweetCount))
        max_id = results[-1].id
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print ("Downloaded {0} tweets, Saved to {1}".format(tweetCount, os.path.abspath(fName)))
        quit()
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print("Error : " + str(e))
        break
```

When run in a Docker container and issued a Keyboard Interrupt it returns

```
Downloaded 520 tweets, Saved to /app/tweets.csv
```

but nothing is saved.

How do I get the script to write out in the container, also what is happening under the hood here?

Edit:

Commands Run:

```
docker build -t dock .
docker run dock
```

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
    enter code here
```

Comment: Can we see the `Dockerfile`? Did you mount a volume to the container? To persist data in docker you have to either mount a specific folder in the guest OS (container) to a specific directory on the host OS (actual computer). You can otherwise you docker volumes which is a slight abstraction to that. But, nonetheless, show us the `Dockerfile`

Comment: I added the Dockerfile above.

Comment: Can you also add the command you use to run this docker contanier?

Comment: @atayenel I added them above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your docker command , it seems that you are not mounting your local directory to your docker container. Docker containers have a different filesystem from the host and files saved in docker containers are get lost once the container is removed. To fix this, run your command like this:

```
docker run  -v /User/Seth/some/local/directory:/app/ dock
```

This commands binds your local directory that you defined before the `:` to the directory `app` inside the docker container. You should check that the local directory exists, and it should be the absolute path. As your docker container runs in `/app`,it will download the tweets.csv there and you should be able to see it in your `/some/local/directory` after it is completed. You might also see your whole codebase as you are downloading the file to the same directory with your code.

Here is the link for [Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

---

*Just for completeness, this has nothing to do with keyboard interrupt.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! And thanks for the link