# Docker not saving ouput to file

Tags: python, docker

Originally posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031907/docker-not-saving-file-on-keyboardinterrupt) on the subject. After answer the csv was saving to the indicated directory. Now it'll create a new directory(/data) but the csv isn't there. I'm not sure why this is no longer working. Without the docker the python script runs as intended.

Commands I'm running:

```
docker build -t dock ./search_api
docker run -v ~/twitter-data/data:/app/ dock
```

And getting the following ouput:

```
Downloaded 220 tweets, Saved to /search/tweets.csv
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /search

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /search

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "search.py"]
```

Search.py is appending to tweets.csv

Answer (score 1):

Your binding to the wrong directory in the container. If you are receiving output saying `Saved to /search/tweets.csv` then you need to bind mount a directory to `/search` not to `app`.

As of now you are mapping the directory `/app` from inside the container to your host machine, which I presume is empty even inside the container.

To fix your problem simply change your docker run command to:

`$ docker run -v ~/twitter-data/data:/search/ dock`

Comment: When naming the file app.py and then having everything as /app in the Dockerfile i get the following error:    python: can't open file 'app': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. This is what had me change to /search and search.py.

Comment: Leave the file named `search.py`, as well as everything in the original question. Only change the docker run command to what I supplied above, I think it should fix your problem.

Comment: That was my same thinking but it just returns python: can't open file 'search': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I think you may have changed something else in your Dockerfile. The change I suggested should have no effect on anything to do with Python. If Python was able to open the directory before my change, it should still be able to do so afterwards.

Comment: Everything is being done as stated. I found this https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1616 , but I'm not running through a VM so not sure if it applies.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it's because the volume was `~/twitter-data/data` but the `search.py`/`app.py` was in the `search_api` directory. Thanks for the help, sorry I didn't give all the info.

```
twitter-data
├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── __pycache__
│   └── config.cpython-36.pyc
├── ci
│   └── build-images.sh
├── data
│   └── tweets.csv
├── images
│   └── test
│       └── Dockerfile
└── search_api
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── config.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── app.py
    ├── config.py
    └── requirements.txt
```